# Why is buff/cache getting larger and larger while loading a large number of numpy arrays using a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I'm working on a project where I need to load a large number of `numpy` arrays saved on the disk using a for loop. The system I'm using is Linux.

The image below shows the memory usage during the process

[image: the memory useage]

As you can see, the part of unavailable memory under `buff/cache` can be even larger than the used memory. What is saved on this part of the memory? How can I reduce it?

The script used for loading the arrays is something like this:

```
import numpy as np

tmp = []
slice1, slice2 = [], []
for item in hashes:
    # np.load(item) has a shape (50, 96)
    tmp.append(np.load(item))
tmp = np.concatenate(tmp, axis=0)

mask1 = # a mask used for slicing, a third of the entries will be selected 
mask2 = # a different mask for slicing, a third of the entries will be selected 

slice1 = tmp[mask1]
slice2 = tmp[mask2]
```

Comment: while it is OS/filesystem specific in general, serialized data can easily take more space than in-memory objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the short code segment shown, you may be converting Numpy ndarray objects into list objects while manipulating them.  Try using all Numpy objects and methods.  Also try to avoid **for loops** and use **Numpy vectorized operations** instead.  56GB is a huge amount of memory. Yikes! :-)

**Possible Numpy codes:**

```
import numpy as np 

tmp = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], ndim=2)
tmp = np.zeros((50, 96))
load_object = np.load(filename)   
tmp = np.array(load_object)

# slice1 = [mask range 1]
# slice2 = [mask range 2]
# Numpy vertical stack
result = np.vstack((tmp[slice1], tmp[slice2]))
```

**Numpy Vertical Stack method docs:**
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
np.vstack((a,b))
(output)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

Hopefully that will solve your problem.  I will do some more testing later, and edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I can't come up with an approach other than using a for loop for loading a large number of files, I guess using `np.vstack` has the same effect as using a for loop? Because there will also be a list comprehension within `np.vstack` like `np.vstack([np.load(item) for item in all_hashes])`

Comment: The np.vstack replaces tmp.append(np.load(item)).  I am guessing that the data object converts from ndarray to a list at this point.  Since append is a list operation, and tmp is defined above as tmp = [ ], also a list object.  You can try to use vstack with a tuple of objects in place of a for loop.  If not, you can use a for loop to manage your control flow, as long as all data operations use Numpy.

Comment: I think your list comprehension idea may work.  I am guessing at what you are trying to stack, the entire file objects or selected slices of those file objects.  Np.vstack is a vectorization method that can be used to replace for loops in certain situations.  Numpy has many more. :-)

Comment: I've tried `np.vstack(tuple(np.load(item) for item in all_hashes))` for loading arrays from the disk, but the proportion of `buff/cache` is still as large as the proportion when I use a for-loop. From this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86646/314881), I think the problem is there are too many disk IO operations involved. I think maybe I can bypass this difficulty by writing the loaded files to disk in the first place, then read the files from the disk. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: You are welcome.  Hope you find an answer that will work.